# How to migrate from SQL API code to Google Fusion Table API v1

Tags: javascript, api, google-fusion-tables

I have a javascript web mapping application code built using previous SQL API which has been deprecated recently. I also used JSON to give back results. Now I want to migrate to new fusion table API. I have gone through migration guide but it doesn't make sense. I do not know exactly what to change. I have two tables on one map so 2 API Keys and 2 table keys. After putting them there is no map displayed. Also I have turned ON the API in the console.

```
var map;
var queryUrlHead = 'http://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=';
var queryUrlTail = '&jsonCallback=?';

//url.push('&key=AIzaSyDbZCuKQMgxAMYUatCsohcJkVSXYKhrKAU');
//url.push('&key=AIzaSyBC6PHfBV6HogU1bGaC5edvM_EPvGpT56c');

var layer_1;
var layer_2;
//var tableid_1 = 3775630;
//var tableid_2 = 4313734;
var tableid_1 = 18nnNfr7P_eelXCCOsK-uOFnIWcR2ofIUGLUk4nk;
var tableid_2 = 1mm0HGszLM3_flfblLnddnmvmQr02W-RwEGQxl2w;


function initialize() {
var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(33.7071,-111.3024);

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
   center: latlng,
   zoom: 7,
   mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
   mapTypeControl: true,
   mapTypeControlOptions: {
   style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.HORIZONTAL_BAR,
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT
},
   scaleControl: true,
   scaleControlOptions: {
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
},

});
....
....
....
var layer_1 = new google.maps.FusionTablesLayer(tableid_1);
....
....
var col_list = 'Name';

if(order_list && order_list !== 'Name') {
    query += " ORDER BY " + order_list;
}

var queryurl = encodeURI(queryUrlHead + qry + queryUrlTail);



$.ajax({
   type : "GET",
   url : queryurl,
   dataType : "jsonp",
   success : dataHandlerCallback,
   error : function() {
       alert("AJAX ERROR for " + queryurl);
   }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few differences:

- Different URL (`https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/`  vs `https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1`)
- JSONP vs JSON
- Structure of JSON object returned
- API v1.0 requires attaching an ApiKey in the URL
- API v1.0 may have a few bugs to work out (e.g. NaN vs numbers in the result)

**SQL API example**

[https://www.google.com/fusiontables/api/query?sql=SELECT%20ETHUN,%20COUNT%28%29%20FROM%204579147%20GROUP%20BY%20ETHUN&alt=json-in-script&jsonCallback=onResponse](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20ETHUN,%20COUNT%28%29%20%20FROM%201Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI%20GROUP%20BY%20ETHUN)

which returns this JSON:

```
onResponse({
   "table":{"cols":["ETHUN","count()"],
   "rows":[
       ["1",3308],
       ["2",18702],
       ["-9",10768]

    ]}
})
```

**Google Fusion Table API v1.0 Example**

[https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20ETHUN%2C%20COUNT()%20%20FROM%201Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI%20GROUP%20BY%20ETHUN&key=MyEncryptedAPIKey](https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql=SELECT%20ETHUN,%20COUNT%28%29%20%20FROM%201Nynh5pPrj1q8JqbalppAm-qzAsgKvL0ZRala7VI%20GROUP%20BY%20ETHUN)

Note I didn't include my API key in the above query, assuming posting it publicly is not a good idea.  So the above link may return a complaint that the key is missing.  But querying it with a valid API key returns the following JSON:

Returns this object:

```
{
 "kind": "fusiontables#sqlresponse",
 "columns": [ "ETHUN",  "count()"  ],
 "rows": [
  [  NaN,  "3308" ],
  [  NaN, "18702" ],
  [  NaN, "10768" ]
 ]
}
```

Comment: What do I need to change in this(below) to get the JSON result and display it?
    $.ajax({
       type : "GET",
       url : queryurl,
       dataType : "jsonp",
       success : dataHandlerCallback,
       error : function() {
           alert("AJAX ERROR for " + queryurl);
       }
    });

Comment: Not having tested this, I believe you use a GET request as you do, dataType="json" (not "jsonp"), and include your api key.

Comment: not working. I tried all combinations. Can you give working example on my code

Answer (score 0):

The queryUrlHead needs to be 'https://www.googleapis.com/fusiontables/v1/query?sql='

Also, you don't need a json callback in queryUrlTail because the new API will return json by default.

Comment: map shows up, tables show up but the JSON result is not showing, returning  AJAX error